# How do I uninstall .NetCore 3.0.0-preview7?

Tags: .net-core

dotnet --info shows that I have

```
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0-preview7.19365.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0-preview7-27912-14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0-preview7-27912-14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

I want to uninstall them but I do not see them in Control Panel ->Programs and features

I tried re-downloading the installer but it does not give an un-install option

> [image: install screen]

Answer (score 0):

You should try downloading the installer of the .NET core with the same version as you want to uninstall (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0) and launching it. 
It will give you the option to uninstall that version. 
You may have to install it and uninstall it.
If it dosen't give you the option to uninstall it install it first, close the window. Then relaunch the installer and you should have it.